# How to detect non-homogeneity

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, histogram

Below are the samples of NDVI images and belonging histograms. Quite often, there is a mixture of various patterns in the single image that might represent either multiple fields, disease or any other combination of patterns. In case of single pattern, the distribution would be normal, whereas in case of combinations, there are multiple distributions combined - usually there are multiple peaks.

Does anyone know what kind of measures besides variance could tell how the samples are spread and how many patterns (or peaks) are there combined in the observed area?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You could say that there are $n$ normal peaks if the $3n-1$ parameter model mixing $n$ normal distributions has a higher Akaike Information Criterion than models with other values of $n$.